# What is a minimal viable number of hosts for an experimental Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, infrastructure

For example, to play with Docker Swarm in a way which makes sense you need 2 or better 3 hosts, right?

What is that number for K8S?

Comment: This is a pretty cool way to get lots of cores running. . .
https://hackernoon.com/diy-kubernetes-cluster-with-x86-stick-pcs-b0b6b879f8a7?gi=1437dce18a5e

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say the minimal viable configuration to test and get a good overview of pod placement would be 5 machines, 2 masters and 3 nodes.
This allows you to play with a master failure, placement of multiple pods "stretched" across the cluster, etc.